# How to check if a sequence could be turned into a palindrome

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, palindrome

I have to find if a list can be a palindrome.  The first part of my program sorts the list.

```
A = [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0]
# sorted:
B = [0, 0, 97, 97, 99, 99, 100, 100]
```

This list can be a palindrome because it can be reordered to:

```
[0, 97, 99, 100, 100, 99, 97, 0]
```

I wrote the following code to return True if the list can be a palindrome.

```
i=0
counter = 0

while i<len(B):
    if i+1 < len(B):
        if B[i]==B[i+1]:
            print(B[i],B[i+1])
            i+=2
        else:
            i+=1
            counter += 1
    else:
        i+=1

if counter<2:
    return True
return False
```

However, if I test the list `[0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0, 1]`, it enters something that looks like a infinite loop.  How can I correctly check if a list could be a palindrome?

Comment: Checking for palindromes in python can be accomplished by using `l == l[::-1]`.

Comment: You have a missing "=" in the `i+1` line. It should be `i+=1`

Comment: @g.d.d.c is supposed that my list is listed as in the example, so I can not go reverse but I need to check if numbers are in couple or are in couple + 1 extra element

Comment: Count the number of element occurences. If there's one element that appears odd number of times and the rest appear an even number of times, or every element appears an even number of times, then your list could be reordered to form a palindrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As we traverse `B`, we can use a set to keep track of what elements have an odd number so far (using a set here is much faster than a list):

```
odds = set()
for i in B:
    if i in odds:
        odds.remove(i)
    else:
        odds.add(i)
```

Then if the length of `odds` is 0 or 1, print `True`. Otherwise print `False`.

```
print len(odds) <= 1 # prints the value you're looking for
```

As noted by @Antti, this can be sped up by taking the attribute lookup outside of the loop, if you are optimizing for performance (about 20% speed boost):

```
odds = set()
remove = odds.remove
add = odds.add
for i in B:
    if i in odds:
        remove(i)
    else:
        add(i)
print len(odds) <= 1
```

Comment: @leekaiinthesky one more optimization, you can do `remove = odds.remove` and `add = odds.add` to squeeze out even more performance.

Comment: Ah, I am on Python 2.7.9, which explains the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Count the occurrences of each value.  Then check that the number of odd counts is zero or one.  There is no need to sort the list.  This will work for any list of values.

```
from collections import Counter

def can_be_palindrome(data):
    odd = (c % 2 for c in Counter(data).values())
    any(odd)  # skip first odd, if present at all
    return not any(odd)  # ensure no more odds

print(can_be_palindrome([0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0]))  # only even counts, true
print(can_be_palindrome([0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0, 1]))  # one odd count, true
print(can_be_palindrome([0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0, 1, 2]))  # two odd counts, false
print(can_be_palindrome('abcabcd'))  # true
print(can_be_palindrome(['a', 'b', 'a', 1, 1])  # true
```

Answer (score 7):

A fast one (or so I thought): uses a dictionary to calculate `odd` values. Stores the values as keys in dictionary, with values being `True` if the key occurred odd times, `False` for even. Finally return True that the `.values()` only has 0 or 1 `True` element (a.k.a. there was only 0 or 1 elements occurring odd number of times).

The iterator works in a short-circuiting manner. The first `any` will return `True` as soon as the first `True` is met, otherwise it will scan the entire iterator. We then rerun the `any(odd_iter)` - this returns `True` if the iterator yields *another* True (a.k.a odd value). If the first `any` exhausted the iterator, then the second `any` will return `False` outright. Finally we negate this return value and return it from the function.

```
def check_palindrome_sequence(sequence):
    odds = {}
    for i in sequence:
        try:
            odds[i] ^= True
        except KeyError:
            odds[i] = True

    odd_iter = iter(odds.values())
    any(odd_iter)
    return not any(odd_iter)

A = [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0]
print(check_palindrome_sequence(A))  # True

A = [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0, 1]    
print(check_palindrome_sequence(A))  # True

A = [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0, 1, 2]
print(check_palindrome_sequence(A))  # False
```

---

Timing on Python 2.7:

```
In [1]: %timeit antti(ls)
1 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit davidism(ls)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit leek(ls)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop
```

The data was identical for all 3:

```
ls = list(range(100000))
ls *= 2
ls += [ 1, 2 ]
random.shuffle(ls)
```

Timing on Python 3, again the data identical:

```
In [1]: %timeit leek(ls)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.4 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit antti(ls)
10 loops, best of 3: 89.3 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit davidism(ls)
10 loops, best of 3: 52 ms per loop
```

leek's is the best overall for completely random. nettux's answer is slowing quadratically, must be taking a minute for 100000 * 2 + 2 elements, and I didn't have patience to time it.

For small values that were a palindrome it is pretty much win for leek

```
In [1]: %timeit leek(ls)                         
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.21 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit antti(ls)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.52 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit davidism(ls)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.45 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way of doing it if the numbers also need to be in sequence (as in `[1,1,2,2,3]` would work, but not `[1,1,2,3,3]`), it just requires splitting the sorted list by every 2 characters

```
def palindrome( input ):
    B = sorted(input)

    #Get every even index
    firstPart = B[::2]
    #Get every odd index
    secondPart = B[1::2]
    #Fix for if there's an odd number of indexes
    if len(secondPart) < len(firstPart):
        secondPart.append( B[-1] )
    #Return true or false
    return firstPart==secondPart


print palindrome( [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 0] )
#True
print palindrome( [0, 99, 97, 97, 99, 100, 100, 0] )
#True
print palindrome( [0, 94, 97, 97, 99, 100, 0] )
#False
```

Also shortened down a bit but it's less readable this way:

```
def palindrome( B ):
    B=sorted(B)
    if len(B)%2:
        B+=[B[-1]]
    return B[::2]==B[1::2]
```

Comment: That would be applicable only if the center element were the largest in case of odd number of elements try [1,1,2,3,3]

Comment: Why? It could form a palindrome if reordered: [1,3,2,3,1]

Comment: Oh, I get you now aha, I was thinking it had to be in sequence :)

Comment: Would you mind adding an edit? It could lead to some confusion.

Comment: This works very fast for even numbered sequences, but fails on odd if the center indeed is not the largest element.